# Passing a custom hash in Angular application output chunks

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

Is there any way or workaround to generate a custom hash and passing it to Angular CLI output hashing. Currently the hash is generated by the Angular CLI. A possible use case is maintaining a version of the output chunks.